# How to change wrong mime type for msi file?

Tags: opensuse, mime-types

`file -i <here msi file>` returns `application/vnd.ms-office` and I think that is wrong. I need a more specific mime type for msi files. I know about magic files.
I have no internet on this PC so I need edit file manually. How can i correctly do that?

Comment: What is it exactly you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my RHEL system, the `file` command sits ontop of `libmagic` and uses that to do the file magic detection. The magic is defined at `/usr/share/misc/magic` (with symlinks to that file at `/usr/share/file/magic` and `/usr/share/magic`). The syntax of the file is a little complicated (understandably) but it should be described under `man 5 magic` if not [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) is an online copy of the man page.